Why is the intercept removed from the multinomial logit model in conjoint analysis?
I have seen multiple resources on Conjoint Analysis which the analyst using a Multinomial Logit model and drops the intercept or recommends dropping the intercept from the model. I have not really seen an explanation for why one should drop the intercept from the Multinomial Logit Model for Conjoint Analysis, though?
Does anyone know why one would drop the intercept for Conjoint Analysis? What does this mean for interpretation and why would one do this?
Furthermore, MaxDiff is sort of a close cousin of Conjoint in the Discrete Choice Model space. Should you also drop the intercept in Conjoint Analysis?
https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/choice-modeling-for-marketing-in-r/building-choice-models?ex=4
https://rpubs.com/ecohee/CBC-11488
